# Request middleware python

Tags: python, python-requests, middleware

As I am using multiple API's for my work, I noticed that I often get connection errors and timeouts after doing requests. As I would like to avoid that easily, I'd like to create a middleware that would be able to get all requests sent from my project and retry them in case there is an error.

For example, let's say that I have 2 requests to 2 differents api in different files like this:

- request1.py

```
request1 = requests.post('url', data)
```

- request2.py

```
request2 = requests.get('url', data)
```

And I would like my middleware to do like

- middleware.py

```
if request:
  try:
     request
  except Error:
     # redo request
```

And the goal would be that if for example request1 crash, the middleware retry the request until it gets a result and the value would be put in my variable request1, would something like this be possible ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: of course is possible, just code it, also can check if some element is present always on response to validate good answer or retry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the requests documentation, there is a section on [retries](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-automatic-retries).

Example:

```
from urllib3.util import Retry
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = Session()
retries = Retry(
    total=3,
    backoff_factor=0.1,
    status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504],
    allowed_methods={'POST'},
)
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

# make your requests
s.get('url')
```

There is also the [tenacity](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library that you can use. Example:

```
# exponential backoff configured for retries
from tenacity import retry

@retry(wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=1, min=4, max=10))
def fetch_data(url, params):
    requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is indeed possible to create a middleware to handle retries for your API requests in case of connection errors or timeouts.

Here's an example of how you could create the middleware:

```
import requests
import time

def retry_request(request_func, max_retries=3, retry_delay=1):
    retries = 0

    while retries < max_retries:
        try:
            response = request_func()
            response.raise_for_status()  # Check if the response was successful
            return response
        except (requests.RequestException, ConnectionError, TimeoutError) as e:
            print(f"Request failed: {e}")
            retries += 1
            time.sleep(retry_delay)

    raise Exception("Max retries exceeded. Request failed.")

# Usage example:
# from api_middleware import retry_request
# response = retry_request(lambda: requests.get('url', data))
# Use 'response' variable to access the API response data.
```

Let me know if is it helpful or not?